# what's the special meaning of $ as argv in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I wrote a simple c application and test on centos 6.5, the code as below

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

when I run the app with `./test $`, then the print value is `$`, but if I run with `./test $$`, the print value changed to `119688`, is any special meaning of `$` in `linux`, I found it works correctly on windows.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-special-variables.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$$` is the current process' ID:

```
[mhawke@localhost-localdomain ~]$ echo $$
10062
[mhawke@localhost-localdomain ~]$ ps -ef | grep bash
mhawke   10062 10056  0 10:48 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
```

When you run your program from the command line the shell is substituting the `$$` for the process ID and your program receives that as its first argument.

To pass `$$` to your program simply wrap it in single quotes:

```
[mhawke@localhost-localdomain ~]$ ./test '$$'
```

From the [`bash`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) man page:

> BASHPID
>
> Expands to the process id of the current bash process. This differs from $$ under certain circumstances, such as subshells that do
>   not require bash to be re-initialized.